# Test-Connection Performance Slow

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I have a list of devices that I would like to ping against to see if they are active or not. If they are active (even if not), I would like to log to a file. So, the active devices go to one file, and the "unpingable" devices are written to another file. The script I have below works okay for a smaller sampling of computers, but when I add the complete list, the "test-connection" section of the script takes hours to complete (about 8,000 devices).  Is there a way to improve the performance by running the command in parallel? In my search, i came across this wrapper function by David Wyatt => [TestConnectionAsync](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Multithreaded-PowerShell-0bc3f59b#content) but I'm unsure how to make it work with separating results in two files. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
ForEach ($PC in $Computer_List) {
  If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $PC -Quiet -Count 1) {
    Add-Content -value $PC -Path "$UPpath"
  } Else {
    Add-Content -Value $PC -Path "$DOWNpath"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from `Test-ConnectionAsync` makes this quite easy:

> When you specify the -Quiet switch of Test-ConnectionAsync, it returns a collection of PSCustomObjects with the properties "ComputerName" and "Success".  Success is the boolean value you'd have received from Test-Connection -Quiet ; the PSCustomObject just allows you to associate that result with the target address.

So all you've got to do is:

1. Ping all computers and capture the output
2. Look at the `Success` attribute to see if you should put it in one file or another

---

```
# 1. Gather ping results
$TestResults = $ComputerList | Test-ConnectionAsync -Quiet

# 2. Loop through results and look at Success
foreach($Result in $TestResults){
    $FilePath = if($Result.Success){
        $UPpath
    } else {
        $DOWNpath
    }
    Add-Content -Path $FilePath -Value $Result.ComputerName
}
```

Comment: It makes perfect sense. Thanks, Mathias.